# open as lens not working in Einstien Analytics Dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard

I have a classic dashboard which has around 10-11 widgets of different type. As classic dashboards are retiring in Nov'19, we want to convert this dashboard to an Einstein Analytics Dashboard. 
When we are trying to do so, the open as lens button is not working on widget. 
Without this, we could not able to convert using pure JSON as the syntax is different between both version.
Can anyone help me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear it is too late for that.

The winter release was rolled out October 14th. And classic dashboard are not accessible anymore at all.
[Salesforce Winter '20](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/09/sandbox-winter-20-release.html)